# Android Google Maps API Key v1 v2 troubles

Tags: android, api, md5

I've been attempting to get v2 of google maps android to work.

Its not the coding thats bothering me though. I can't even get started

I've followed various articles and tutorials on how to obtain the key, I have my MD5 key, which I wont post but obviously it looks like:

xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx: etc..

On Googles API console I have clicked on 'create new android key' and entered my MD5 key as follows:

xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx;com.example.project

I have done this a few times, obtained my MD5 a few times using various iterations of -keytool, its always the same so I'm fairly sure the key is correct.

I keep getting 'Invalid input', any ideas?

Upto now I wasn't aware google had deprecated their previous API, rendering about 3/4 tuts on the internet on Maps development redundant and I'm obviously stuck if i can't obtain a key for V2. Please Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Maps API V2 works with `SHA1` fingerprint and not `MD5`.
I guess this is the reason it doesn't works for you.

You can take a look at this blog post I wrote on how to get a key for API V2:

[Google Maps API V2 Key](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=403)

Comment: I thought the API console took an MD5 and generated an SHA1 from that?

Comment: No, you have to supply the API Console your SHA1 fingerprint. Take a look at the blog post guide to get an idea of how to get it.

Comment: you the man for the Tutorial!! thing is I'm using Ubuntu, also I have the following output:

Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

androiddebugkey, 06-May-2013, PrivateKeyEntry, 
Certificate fingerprint (MD5): xx:xx:xx:Xx:Xx:Xx etc.

the command I used was: keytool -list -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore

Sorry I dont know how to encapsulate code in comments :/

Comment: I'm not familiar with Ubuntu, sorry. But I see you already got your answer : )

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu run this command:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```